# Converting a large SQL Server Database to Azure Storage

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have a very large database structure, (Data is not important at this point, I can migrate the info in the db pretty easily if the structure is done) , all reside in SQL Server and I even published it to SQL Azure, but thinking about the limitation of SQL Azure in size, made me decide to switch most of the tables that do not need all the bells and whistles of SQL Azure to Azure Table and blob storage.

I was thinking of creating a TT template that dose that, but was wondering if their is a tool that do that.

Any ideas or thoughts?

The only tables that i would keep in SQL Azure would anything related to transactions like  payments.

Comment: I used codesmith old template to get the Data to the new format, since no suggestion was posted, I thought to let anyone who is looking for something similar

Comment: I'd love to see the t4 template, i've been thinking about creating the opposite (table storage -> sql tables)

Comment: for sure will post it later today, need to clean it up, I think its 2 files, Its not T4 , old CodeSmith format

Answer (score 0):

BTW, 50GB SQL Azure databases are coming in June should you have a project where you need a relational db, but the current 10GB isn't big enough.

Comment: Please don't use signatures, particularly ones with links.  You're welcome to put a link to your web site or blog on your user profile page. Also, please don't use link obfuscator services.  People like to see where a link is going before they click it.